# List container in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java (about 1.5 years) and this is my short project. I created a simple container wich can take an array and value of generic type `T` (like Integer, Double and so on). It can take values sorted and unsorted and remove an element from the container, and every method describes it. I don't know whether I am using `Optional` and `instanceof` correctly.

```
import java.util.Optional;

interface List<T> {

    void showAll();

    void addOnBack(T n);

    void add(T n);

    void addSorted(T n);

    int size();

    T getNode(int n);

    void removeNode(int n);

    <T> void reverse(Element top);

}

class Container<T> implements List<T> {

    private Element<T> top = null;
    private Element<T> current = null;
    private Element<T> last = null;
    private Element<T> insert = null;
    private Element<T> previous = null;
    Optional<T> optional = Optional.empty();

    public Container() {
    }

    public Container(int tab[]) {
        for (int a : tab) {
            T t = (T) (Integer) a;
            this.add(t);
        }
    }

    public Container(double tab[]) {
        for (double a : tab) {
            T t = (T) (Double) a;
            this.add(t);
        }
    }

    public Container(T tab[]) {
        for (T t : tab) {
            this.add(t);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T n) {
        optional = Optional.ofNullable(n);
        while (optional.isPresent()) {
            current = new Element<>(n);
            if (top == null) {
                top = current;
            } else {
                last.next = current;
            }
            last = current;
            System.out.println("number " + current.num);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addOnBack(T n) {
        optional = Optional.ofNullable(n);
        if (optional.isPresent()) {

            current = new Element<>(n);
            current.next = top;

            top = current;
            System.out.println("number " + top.num);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showAll() {
        current = top;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.num);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addSorted(T n) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        insert = new Element<>(n);
        previous = null;
        current = top;
        if (current != null && current.num instanceof Integer) {
            a = (Integer) n;
        }

        while (current != null && current.num instanceof Integer
                && (b = (Integer) current.num) < a) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        while (current != null
                && current.num instanceof String
                && current.num.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(n.toString()) < 0) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        insert.next = current;
        if (previous == null) {
            top = insert;
        } else {
            previous.next = insert;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        current = top;
        while (current != null) {
            size++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public T getNode(int n) {
        int size = this.size();
        Element<T> searchingNumber = top;
        Element<T> target = null;
        T t = null;
        if (n <= size() && searchingNumber != null) {
            for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
                target = searchingNumber;
                System.out.println("inside loop " + searchingNumber.num);
                searchingNumber = searchingNumber.next;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("indexOut");
        }
        if (target != null) {
            t = target.num;
        } else {
            System.out.println("null");
        }

        return t;
    }

    public Element<T> getTop() {
        return this.top;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeNode(int n) {
        if (n <= 0 || n > size()) {
            System.out.println("indexOut");
        } else {
            if (n == 1) {
                top = top.next;
            }
            current = null;
            current = top;

            if (current != null) {
                for (int a = 1; a < n; a++) {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }

            if (n > 1) {
                previous.next = current.next;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public <T> void reverse(Element top) {
        if (top != null) {
            reverse(top.next);
            System.out.println(top.num);
        }
    }

}

class Element<T> {

    T num;
    Element next;

    public Element(T n) {
        num = n;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: While it is good (and necessary) to include your code, this is not sufficient for a question on Code Review. Please add a few sentences describing what this project achieves.

Comment: I fixed some typos and grammar in your question. Unfortunately I don't understand what you mean by "and every method describe[s] it". It sounds ungrammatical. Could you explain what you meant by that?

Comment: Is `double tab[]` valid syntax? I might be mistaken, but this looks like C syntax to me. Is it not `double[] tab` in Java?

Comment: @RaimundKrämer Java allows both, although latter is more common.

Answer (score 1):

### Design and Logic

You defined your own version of the `List` interface. I am not sure if you intended to reinvent the wheel, but usually, even if you write your own List implementation, it is good to use the existing interface. That way you can exchange your implementation for another one, or vice versa.

The methods it defines are different from the existing Java `List` interface, but maybe you can derive your List from the Java version with a new name and extend it with additional methods. Maybe even the `Deque` fits better.

The names you chose are atypical. Renaming `addOnBack` to `addLast` would be more consistent to the naming of e. g. the Deque.

---

Your `Container` class implements `List`. While this makes sense when you say "I make my own container that behaves like a list", it is actually contrary to the usual understanding of Java containers. A List is a container, just like Sets and others are containers. If you make your own implementation of List, it should be a List as well. From that it looks like to me, it is a double-chained linked list. `DoubleLinkedList` or `Deque` (short for double ended queue) might be a better name.

---

```
<T> void reverse(Element top);
```

You don't use the generic type in that method, so you could remove it from the definition.

The method should not need `top` as a parameter. It can access the member variable `top` anyway, and you wouldn't expect a list to need a parameter just to reverse itself.

The implementation of the method also does not fit the name. If I understand it correctly, it does not reverse the list, but rather just print the elements from front to back. And not even just from itself, but I think it would even do that for another list if you passed it an element from another instance.

Furthermore, it should not print anything, as the name suggests differently.

---

You are printing stuff in multiple methods where printing should not be done, e. g. `add`. Every method should do only one thing, i. e. `add` should do no more than adding an element. You have the method `showAll` that does nothing except printing the whole list, so you can use that if you want to inspect the list's current state.

---

```
    while (optional.isPresent()) {
        current = new Element<>(n);
        if (top == null) {
            top = current;
        } else {
            last.next = current;
        }
        last = current;
        System.out.println("number " + current.num);
        break;
    }
```

This could be just an if-statement, since you break out of the loop after the first "round" anyway.

---

```
int size = this.size();
```

You have this line at the beginning of the `getNode` method, but it seems like you are not using the variable.

---

Your implementation of `size()` is quite inefficient, because it has linear time complexity while it could be done in constant time. To do that, save the size in a member variable and update it every time you add or remove an element. If you add multiple elements add once, update it only once with the size of the array (or collection). Otherwise asking the container for its size could take relatively long if it contains lots of elements.

---

The method `addSorted` is a little weird. Adding an element to a list between a lower and a higher element does not make sense if the list is not sorted already. So I'd suggest to change the method to `addAndSort`, or better just add the element and then sort the whole list alltogether.

There are sorting algorithms that are, even though quite inefficient in the average case, very efficient if the list is already close to being sorted, e. g. Insertion Sort (which works close to how you are inserting your element in `addSorted`, but for the entire list).

---

```
    if (n <= 0 || n > size()) {
        System.out.println("indexOut");
    }
```

Here you should throw an exception (for more info see below, where I talk about the style of the `removeNode` method. But since this is about logic: It is really unusual to index a container starrting at 1. Arrays and lists are indexed starting at 0 in Java, and also in most other common programming languages.

The check should look like this:

```
if (n < 0 || n >= size())
```

If course you would also have to adjust the else part.

### Style

Using blank lines to structure your code and group logically related lines can be good, but separating all lines of the interface definition does not really improve readability, rather the contrary.

---

Instead of `this.size();`, you can just write `size()`, because there is no naming conflict. Note however that, as stated above, the line where it occurs is obsolete anyway.

---

In `removeNode` you have this:

```
    if (n <= 0 || n > size()) {
        System.out.println("indexOut");
    } else {
        // long block of code
    }
```

Where I made the comment, you have about 20 lines of code nested inside an else. There are two ways to improve that.

1. The recommended way: Instead of printing something to the console when the index is out of range, you could (or rather should) throw an exception (IndexOutOfRangeException). Since that will automatically stop the execution of the method, you could remove the else and save an indentation level.
2. If you really want to print out the message instead of throwing an exception, you could still manually `return` at the end of the if-block. Then again you can remove the else, since the execution won't even reach that part of code if the index is out of range.

Comment: Thanks for reply and constructive analysis. I dont't reinvent the wheel. This is training for me. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this one

```
public Container(int tab[]) {
    for (int a : tab) {
        T t = (T) (Integer) a;
        this.add(t);
    }
}

public Container(double tab[]) {
    for (double a : tab) {
        T t = (T) (Double) a;
        this.add(t);
    }
}

public Container(T tab[]) {
    for (T t : tab) {
        this.add(t);
    }
}
```

to

```
public Container(T tab[]) {
    for (T t : tab) {
        this.add(t);
    }
}
```

Why do you need 2 uneccessary constructors?

Comment: When I do it this and then past Double value is not any problem but when you try the same with double compiler return error "cannot infer type arguments".

Comment: Should use Double.valueOf insteads

Comment: I understand what you mean but how write it? How one generic constructor can infer value? If-statment? In constructor? There is add() method which take a T value. The compiler check this before compilation. I think it doesn't solution for this specific situation.